# IPython notebook kernel dies on import

Tags: ipython, enthought

I am running IPython Notebook on Enthought's Canopy 64 bit distribution, Ubuntu 14.04.

I've tried install libtiff, but when I import it in IPython Notebook, the kernel always dies at the import statement.  What could possibly be causing this?  Canopy is my default Python distribution, my paths all seem like they're set up appropriately, although I'm convinced that something in my Python setup is borked.

Any advice is appreciated.

EDIT: I'll be more specific.  Output of sys.path:

```
    ['',
 '/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/src/svn',
 '/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python27.zip',
 '/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/home/joe/opencv-2.4.9',
 '/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

As for how to install Python packages, I assume I go to ~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages and run pip, setup.py, or a shell script, per the specific package's instructions.  Is that correct?  The article that I linked has the following line: "To install a package which is not available in the Canopy / EPD repository, follow standard Python installation procedures from the OS command line.", which seems to imply that I install per package instructions.

In .bashrc, I have the following:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate    
export PYTHONHOME=/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin
export PATH=/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin
export PYTHONPATH=/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin
```

From what I understand of the linked articles, this means I'm setting Canopy User as my default Python distribution.  I'm sure I'm doing something a bit over my head here, but I can't understand what else I need to do to fix this issue.

Worse yet, now I'm getting an "ImportError: No module named site" with these .bashrc settings, when trying to start IPython notebook or python from the command line.  I can run only from the Canopy GUI.

Comment: From our discussions off of SO, it sounds like you installed tiff / pylibtiff into your system Python, not Canopy User Python. It's important to make sure Canopy is the active Python (`which python`) before installing with `pip`.

Comment: Also, when you look at `sys.path` in your Canopy Python, there should be no system python paths there, and vice versa.

Comment: I did install tiff/pylibtiff into system Python, not Canopy User Python, per the instructions, and what I understood of the supplied article (https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-User-Python-from-the-OS-command-line).  Did I misread the article?  I assumed installing from the /home/joe directory was the appropriate way to go.  None of these were installed via pip.

Comment: I'm installing these packages into /Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages.  They don't seem to be found.

Also, sys.path shows no python paths in Canopy python.

Comment: If your sys.path shows no python paths in Canopy Python, then you are not running Canopy Python. And yes, you mis-read the article. See https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python (linked in that article) for more details.

Comment: Edited for additional detail.  As far as I understand, my Python build is set to Canopy Python as the default.

Answer (score 1):

Closing this.  I made it harder than necessary.

It turns out, the PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH .bashrc variables were causing some conflicts.  Commenting them out seems to have resolved the issue.

Installing outside packages does, indeed, happen from the home (~) directory.